# Add 2 variables together to make another variable

Tags: php

What am I doing wrong here to get undefined variable notice.

```
if (isset(${$error_description_.$i}[$lang])) {
```

Previously I had this:

```
if (isset($error_description_1[$lang])) {
```

I now have this inside a for loop where 1 is replaced.

Comment: if (isset($error_description_.$i[$lang])) { please be more specific

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (isset(${"error_description_".$i}[$lang])) {
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, what is this type of syntax called? I would like to read the docs page

Comment: You’re welcome. You may read the PHP manual to know more about [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if (isset(${'error_description_' . $i}[$lang])) {
}
```